# Middleware to redirect unauthenticated and authenticated users accordingly

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js 13 with the `app` directory. And I was trying to add a `middleware` that redirects unauthenticated users to `/login` page.

But I also want to redirect authenticated users when they try to `/login` page

```typescript
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const verified = //Verification

    if (verified) {
        const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
        return NextResponse.next({
            request: {
                headers: requestHeaders,
            },
        })
    } else {
        url.pathname = '/login';
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/",
    ],
};
```

Is there a way to do this using middleware.

Comment: Because of your current `matcher`, your middleware will only run for `"/"` path. Is there any other problem?

Comment: If I try to add `"/login"` to my `matcher`, it will give me an error of `"too many redirections"`. So I am asking of another way to do that

Comment: I see. I have posted an answer, check it out and let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a config `matcher` for all the paths you want the middleware to run on, and a well set of `if` statements well put together, as an example:

```typescript
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

const authPahts = ["/login", "/signup", "reset"];

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const verified = true; // Update your condition here
  if (verified) {
    console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname);
    if (authPahts.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
    }
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
    return NextResponse.next({
      request: {
        headers: requestHeaders,
      },
    });
  } else {
    if (authPahts.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
      return NextResponse.next();
    }
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
};
```

Comment: I adjusted this code to my routes, but it still gave me the `"too many redirections"` error. But now added a verification on the `login` page itself.